# Converting Column with string separated values into rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement the below: I know how to use 2 columns but I need to extend it to more than 2 columns. In other words, var2 and var3 need to be replicated and extended down and mapped to each value in var1 col.

```
                  var1   var2        var3
0          47429,47404  10700  1403298300
1    23030,23831,23147  99999  1403297100
```

Trying to get:

```
   var1    var2  var3
0  47429  10700  1403298300
1  47404  10700  1403298300
2  23030  99999  1403297100
3  23831  99999  1403297100
4  23147  99999  1403297100
```

This code from another post only uses two columns as opposed to 3:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(row['var2'], row['var1'].split(','))\
    for _, row in testdf.iterrows()]).reset_index()[:5]
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question.. Can you clarify "var2 and var3 need to be replicated and extended down and mapped to each value in var1 col"?

Comment: Sure. Updated question to make it much more clear. Sorry about the horrible wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one big oneliner:

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]: 
                var1   var2        var3
0        47429,47404  10700  1403298300
1  23030,23831,23147  99999  1403297100

In [108]: pd.concat((pd.Series((v, row['var2'], row['var3']), df.columns) for _, row in df.iterrows() for v in row['var1'].split(',')), axis=1).T
Out[108]: 
    var1   var2        var3
0  47429  10700  1403298300
1  47404  10700  1403298300
2  23030  99999  1403297100
3  23831  99999  1403297100
4  23147  99999  1403297100
```

The inner nested generators are the ones doing the trick. 
They basically doing the same work as these for-loops:

```
In [112]: for _, row in df.iterrows():
    for v in row['var1'].split(","):
        print (v, row['var2'], row['var3'])
   .....:         
('47429', 10700, 1403298300)
('47404', 10700, 1403298300)
('23030', 99999, 1403297100)
('23831', 99999, 1403297100)
('23147', 99999, 1403297100)
```

I also added the column-headers of the original data-frame to the produced `Series`.

Finally, since I'm no pandas expert, I resolved concatenating the series along axis 1 and then transposing
the data-frame to get it in the correct structure.