# Much more efficient way to parse and process large files with JSON Objects

Tags: python, json, pandas, bigdata

**How can the code below be optimized?** (and is Python ok for this or should I be using another tool?)

This is by far the craziest question I have asked on SO but I am going to give it a shot in the hope of getting some advice about whether or not I am leveraging the right tools and methods for processing large amounts of data efficiently. I'm not necessarily looking for help on optimizing my code unless there is something I am completely overlooking but essentially would just like to know if I should be going with a different framework all together instead of Python. I'm new enough to Python to not be completely sure if it is possible to process large amount of data and store into DB much more efficiently.

The implementation below reads text files in a directory:

- with each text file containing 50K lines of JSON objects...
- that need to be parsed and read and then converted into a CSV before loading into a database.
- I hate using list containers and I am hoping that there is something else I can research implementing in Python for doing this in a much much better way. My initial thoughts are that I should use generators but not totally sure.
- The crazy concat part at the end is important because it converts a comma-separated list into its own rows. 
  [Converting Column with string separated values into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419551/converting-column-with-string-separated-values-into-rows)

Code:

```
  triggerZipFiles = glob.glob('*.zip')
  for triggerFiles in triggerZipFiles:
      with zipfile.ZipFile(triggerFiles, 'r') as myzip:
          for logfile in myzip.namelist():
              datacc = []
              zipcc = []
              csvout = '{}_US.csv'.format(logfile[:-4])
              f = myzip.open(logfile)
              contents = f.readlines()
              for line in contents:
                  try:
                      parsed = json.loads(line[:-2])
                      if "CC" in parsed['data']['weatherType'] and "US" in parsed['zipcodes']:
                          datacc.append(parsed['data'])
                          zipcc.append(parsed['zipcodes'])
                  except:
                      pass
              if len(datacc) > 0:
                  df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(zipcc), pd.DataFrame(datacc)], axis=1)
                  df = pd.concat((pd.Series((v, row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key'],
                    row['key'], row['key'], row['key'], row['key']), df.columns) for _,
                      row in df.iterrows() for v in row['US']), axis=1).T                
                  df.to_csv(csvout, header=None, index=False)
              else:
                  pass
              print datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') + ": Finished: {}".format(logfile)
```

Comment: One inefficient thing that is easily fixed: the test `x in a_dict.keys()` first creates a list with all keys and then does a _linear_ search for `x` in that list.  Testing containment directly on the `dict` does not create the extra list and has constant runtime.

I would also combine the three `if` statements into one with `and`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please just provide a small example of what testing containment directly on dict would look like?

Comment: The 'key36/62/65' each occur twice in that weird concat construct. Was that intentional?

Comment: @prometheus2305 Simply `x in a_dict` instead of `x in a_dict.keys()`.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help. I have updated the code with my final implementation which is faster than what I originally had. Definitely would like to test out the pandas json library thanks @AndyHayden to see how much faster that might make it.

Comment: Why on earth are you concat'ting `row['key']` 71 times?! Or was that just placeholder code to imply 71 distinct keys? If so, use a column slice something like `df.iloc[:, 2:72]` instead of 71 lookups on a local dict.

Comment: To point out the obvious, your code is essentially a huge converter for N JSON objects into N CSV files before they can be ingested into a DB. Better if you could simply migrate to a DB that handles JSON directly. (Which DB are you using?)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, *lines* isn't a particularly useful metric when it comes to json!
Secondly, you've got the right idea: you definitely want to do this chunk-based (read/clean/dump each part separately).

I recommend using pandas' `read_json` function, it's much more efficient at creating DataFrames (it doesn't create a temporary python dict), *see the [reading in json section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#reading-json).*

- If there not *actually* json, then doing string manipulation to make them json is usually your best bet.*
- If you have "oddly-shaped" json, then you can either [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#normalization) when reading, or parse the columns which contain multiple columns after reading in the DataFrame (e.g. using a Series string method or apply).

**it's unclear what the actual format is, but often it doesn't take much to make them into **valid** json.*

Python bonus tip: if you're more that a few indentation levels deep consider breaking it apart into more functions. (The obvious choice here is to have `f1(logfile)` and `f2(line)`, but using descriptive names...)